# Populate a new column in table A based on a temporary table where there is a shared field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table, A, in my DB that has a Primary Key ID and OtherID (which is currently null for all values). I have created a temporary table, B, with ID and OtherID (all populated with the proper values).

I would like to know how to write a proper SQL Statement that can update each record in A with the corresponding OtherID contained within B.

I am using SQL Server

My initial idea was to use a join between A and B on ID, but I am not sure if this is the proper way to go about doing this. I have a basic understanding of SQL, but the minutiae still eludes me

Comment: you can use Merge - [Standard Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Also - https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an `update` with `join`:

```
update a
    set otherid = b.otherid
    from a join
         b
         on a.id = b.id;
```